# Codename One button with icon - set size according to icon size

Tags: ios, button, icons, codenameone

I have an icon button, with a small squared icon.

The button is embedded in a BoxLayout.

Is there a way to reduce the size of the button, in order to automatically reach the exact size of the icon?

I mean, I know I can change the button's size editing margins and paddings, but I'm asking if I can automatically change it according to the size of the icon embedded in the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Layouts](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/layouts/package-summary.html) in Codename One determine the size based on the components preferred size and their own logic. `BoxLayout` always scales the component to take up the available space on the opposite axis which means the button on a box Y layout will take up the full available width.

So:

```
Button b = ...;
boxYContainer.add(b);
```

The button will take up the full width.

`FlowLayout` gives components their preferred size which works great for deterministic components and not so great for others e.g. it would be bad for `TextArea` where the content can change the preferred size based on text reflow.

So something like this will place the button in the preferred size in the center:

```
Button b = ...;
boxYContainer.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(b));
```

Notice this is shorthand syntax for:

```
Button b = ...;
Container flowLayoutContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER));
flowLayoutContainer.add(b);
boxYContainer.add(flowLayoutContainer);
```